# How to resolve Apache POI not supported setting error?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was using apache POI to write a file from MySQL database and then transposing the written file into a new file. I tried importing a jar file from a colleague's project as a dependency in my module, but this causes my code which had no errors prior, to now throw this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler at this line `Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(dataStream);` and my log says `Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!` How do i fix this error? I need his jar file to be able to call his protected classes which are in separate package. I suspect that my dependencies are clashing with some dependencies that are inside his jar (dom4j-1.5.jar) because whenever I remove his jar, my code works again, but i am unable to instantiate his classes.

edit: I might not be able to modify his jar, so I hope that there could be some modifications i can make to my code or my dependencies so that I can avoid this issue

edit2: I think the issue is stemming from whatever is causing the `Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!` to pop up. I tried removing the dependency = no error, use dependency but comment out below methods = no error. (basically while dependency is not there, my code can write the files no problem, but when dependency is there, this charToByteConverterClass suddenly becomes an issue. Probably due to the encryption/password protection?

```
         //getting the result set using jdbc...
         ResultSet resultSet = Stmt.executeQuery();
         String path = writeFile(resultSet, folderpath, item, cols, password);       //assign to file var so that i can encrypt it
         convertFile(path, password);


private String writeFile(ResultSet res,String path, String sid, String[] columns, String password) throws SQLException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
        Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
        enc.confirmPassword(password);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sid);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        int rowCnt = 0;

        if (res.next()==false){
            Row rowVals = sheet.createRow(rowCnt);
            Cell cell = rowVals.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("There is no data for this timeframe");
        }else{
            while(res.next()){
                Row rowVals = sheet.createRow(rowCnt);
                for (int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
                    Cell cell = rowVals.createCell(i);
                    if (columns[i].equals("reading")){
                        cell.setCellValue(res.getFloat(columns[i]));
                    }else{
                        cell.setCellValue(res.getString(columns[i]));
                    }
                }
                rowCnt++;
            }
        }

        OutputStream encos = enc.getDataStream(fs);
        workbook.write(encos);
        workbook.close();
        encos.close(); // this is necessary before writing out the FileSystem

        String excelpath = path+sid+".xlsx";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(excelpath);
        fs.writeFilesystem(os);
        os.close();
        fs.close();

        return excelpath;
    }

public void convertFile(String path, String password) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new File(path));
        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fileSystem);
        Decryptor decryptor = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

        if (!decryptor.verifyPassword(password)) {
            System.out.println("Unable to process: document is encrypted.");
            return;
        }

        InputStream dataStream = decryptor.getDataStream(fileSystem);

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(dataStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
        int numOfCols = firstSheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

        Workbook transposed = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet transposedSheet = transposed.createSheet();

        ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j=0; j< numOfCols; j++){
            rows.add(transposedSheet.createRow(j));
        }

        int column = 1;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            int i=0;        //iterates the rows
            //iterates the columns
            for (int j=0; j<numOfCols; j++){
                rows.get(j).createCell(0).setCellValue(j+1);
            }
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING){
                    String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    if (cellValue.equals("There is no data for this timeframe")){
                        //if no data, no need to write file.
                        return;
                    }
                    rows.get(i).createCell(column).setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC){
                    rows.get(i).createCell(column).setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                i++;
            }
            column++;
        }

        File convertedFile = new File(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(".")));        //+".txt"
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(convertedFile);

        Iterator<Row> transposedIterator = transposedSheet.iterator();
        int transposedCols = transposedSheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while(transposedIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = transposedIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            int columns = 0;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (columns == transposedCols - 1) {
                    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                        String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        sb.append(cellValue + "\n");
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        sb.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\n");
                    }
                } else {
                    if (columns==0){
                        if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                            String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            sb.append(cellValue + ",");
                        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                            sb.append((int)cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                            String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            sb.append(cellValue + ",");
                        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                            sb.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                        }
                    }
                }
                columns++;
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(sb);
        writer.write(sb.toString());
        writer.close();
        workbook.close();
        fileSystem.close();
    }
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!
210630-15:41:24 [SEVERE] -- mkReqHandler: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler
java.lang.RuntimeException: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:2755)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:2481)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getSaxLoader(Locale.java:2467)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:831)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:820)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:233)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.SstDocument$Factory.parse(SstDocument.java:78)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.readFrom(SharedStringsTable.java:123)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<init>(SharedStringsTable.java:111)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:660)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:278)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:299)
    at LivelyCheck.mkReq.mkReq.convertFile(mkReq.java:581)
    at LivelyCheck.mkReq.mkReq.makeExport(mkReq.java:370)
    at LivelyCheck.mkReq.mkReq.makeExport(mkReq.java:336)
    at LivelyCheck.mkReq.mkReq.exportSid(mkReq.java:327)
    at LivelyCheck.mkReq.mkReqHandler.run(mkReqHandler.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler
    at org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.setProperty(Driver.java:204)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:2749)
    ... 19 more
210630-15:41:24 [INFO] -- TouchDisplayHandler: alert failure --
```

Comment: Use a more modern and featuring supporting xml parsing library?

Comment: Do you have a recommendation? I just recently stumbled onto apache poi and wrote a lot of stuff using it, but i believe i should be able to learn a new library and rewrite everything in a tight deadline. though a quickfix for this scenario would be preferred.

Comment: Java comes with a pretty decent XML parser these days, just use that. Apache POI is happy with pretty much any standards compliant XML parser

Comment: I read from this link that dom4j-1.6 is needed. https://howtodoinjava.com/java/library/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/ would it be a good idea to include for example the latest version of it, so that when running the code, it would refer to the newer version of dom4j from my dependencies before looking at the older version in my colleague's jar?

Comment: I made a quick fix where I combined both methods to remove the need to parse the xlsx files. This may not be an optimal solution, since the error is still there, but i just circumvented it.

Comment: Another quickfix i found: I remove all dependency on my colleague's module, and I recompiled his jar with a specific main class for compile output, then I use a processbuilder to build his jar. This allows me to instantiate his GUI on click of button without his dependencies clashing with my codes